# websocket spring mvc-dispatcher threw exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket

i am using Spring 4. i am trying to make chat application user stomp and sock.js. But i have problem when add websocket configuration in dispatcher-servlet.

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:websocket="http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket/spring-websocket.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- resource -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<!-- resoruce -->

<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/calApp">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/add">
        <websocket:sockjs />
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic" />
</websocket:message-broker>
```

**pom.xml** **[UPDATED]**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
<artifactId>BelajarChat</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>BelajarChat</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>BelajarChat</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**message.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Calculator App Using Spring 4 WebSocket</title>
  <script src="webjars/sockjs-client/1.0.2/sockjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="webjars/stomp-websocket/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var stompClient = null;
    function setConnected(connected) {
      document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
      document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
      document.getElementById('calculationDiv').style.visibility = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('calResponse').innerHTML = '';
    }
    function connect() {
      var socket = new SockJS('/add');
      stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
      stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/showResult', function(calResult){
          showResult(JSON.parse(calResult.body).result);
        });
      });
    }
    function disconnect() {
      stompClient.disconnect();
      setConnected(false);
      console.log("Disconnected");
    }
    function sendNum() {
      var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
      var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
      stompClient.send("/calcApp/add", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'num1': num1, 'num2': num2 }));
    }
    function showResult(message) {
      var response = document.getElementById('calResponse');
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
      p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
      response.appendChild(p);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript><h2>Enable Java script and reload this page to run Websocket Demo</h2></noscript>
<h1>Calculator App Using Spring 4 WebSocket</h1>
<div>
  <div>
    <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>
    <button id="disconnect" disabled="disabled" onclick="disconnect();">Disconnect</button><br/><br/>
  </div>
  <div id="calculationDiv">
    <label>Number One:</label><input type="text" id="num1" /><br/>
    <label>Number Two:</label><input type="text" id="num2" /><br/><br/>
    <button id="sendNum" onclick="sendNum();">Send to Add</button>
    <p id="calResponse"></p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error**

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Don't mix spring versions, you are mixing 4.1.1 and 4.2.2 never mix versions of frameworks (regardless of the framework).

Comment: oh good, i didn't see it @_@ thank's.

Comment: i get same error again :/

Comment: Have you actually read the stack trace? Post it as text not as a screenshot. You have an error in your configuration, the servlet cannot load it.

Comment: hohohoo sory my mistake,
i have 2 method for 1 mesage handler in different class. it make ambiguous method :3 thank's